# AdMob ad don't show

Tags: admob, google-play-services

**My xml file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/quadro"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"`enter code here`
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linha01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linha02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linha03"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linha04"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|left" >

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linhaAd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxx" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    /*...
     *Code
     *...*/

    adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

**Manifest xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
...

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
...

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

**when I change the background of the ad it appears with the black background, but without any text.The adView even creates impressions in AdMob, but don't show.I don't know what can be**

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the RelativeLayout. There is no need for it and you have set it to consume all the height of its parent, which is almost certainly not what you want.